# Issues with converting from string to char** while creating a command prompt

Tags: c++

I am creating a command prompt and I take input from the user as a string and convert it to a char** using a parse function I have created. I can not see any issues with it but after running a few commands in my prompt I begin to run into the error of "corrupted size vs prev_size 0x00c06738. Here is my parse function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
char**  parse(string s){

    vector<string> commandvector;
    istringstream iss(s);

    for(string s; iss>>s;)
        commandvector.push_back(s);

    char** argv = new char*[commandvector.size() + 1];


    for(int i = 0; i<commandvector.size();i++){
        argv[i] = new char[commandvector[i].size()];
        strcpy(argv[i],commandvector[i].c_str());
    }

    argv[commandvector.size() + 1] = NULL;

    return argv;
}
```

Comment: Why are you downgrading to char* when you already got strings?

Comment: `argv[commandvector.size() + 1] = NULL;` accesses the array out of bounds and invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: thanks a ton that fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C-style strings, you have to take into account the null-terminator char.

While [`std::basic_string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns a pointer to a null-terminated (since C++11) array of char, [`std::basic_string::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) doesn't count the null terminator, so in order to allocate enough memory, you have to add 1 to returned value.

Besides, as [UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806108/issues-with-converting-from-string-to-char-while-creating-a-command-prompt#comment80559805_46806108) already noticed, you are accessing the `argv` array outside its bounds, beeing `argv[commandvector.size()]` its last element.